# How to concatenate multiple results into a few generic results in mysql?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I intend to draw a bar graph. The x axis contains labels. The labels are generated from a mysql request. The labels are also too many to fit into a page graph. I intend to combine some of the familiar labels into one. I believe The existign set up is fine however I want to edit my mysql query to suit this problem.

An example to clear the question.

This is my current mysql query

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT HITYPE,
            SUM(IF(STATUS = 'OPEN',1,0)) AS OPEN,
            SUM(IF(STATUS = 'CLOSED',1,0)) AS CLOSED,
            COUNT(STATUS) AS 'TOTAL'
            FROM hazardreport WHERE HITYPE IS NOT NULL AND RISKLEVEL='$risklevel' AND DATE(DREPORTED) BETWEEN '$dateone' AND 
            '$datetwo'
            GROUP BY HITYPE
            ORDER BY TOTAL DESC";
```

The generated data is

```
item1, 1, 0, 1
item1.1 , 3 , 2 , 5
item2 , 1 , 1 , 2
item2.2, 5, 1 , 6
```

I would like to edit the query so that the generated data can be combined to:

```
item 1, 4, 2 , 6
item 2, 6, 2, 8
```

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping the results by the first part of the hitype string value.

```
SELECT HITYPE,
SUM(IF(STATUS = 'OPEN',1,0)) AS OPEN,
SUM(IF(STATUS = 'CLOSED',1,0)) AS CLOSED,
COUNT(STATUS) AS TOTAL
from (
    select SUBSTRING_INDEX(HITYPE, '.', 1) as HITYPE, status
    FROM hazardreport WHERE HITYPE IS NOT NULL AND RISKLEVEL='$risklevel'
    AND DATE(DREPORTED) BETWEEN '$dateone' AND '$datetwo'
) as results
GROUP BY HITYPE
ORDER BY TOTAL DESC
```